# Working with strings and lists in Python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

Determine if a sentence is a palindrome (read the same in both directions).

Example:

text = "MrOwl ate my metal worm" -> This is a palindrome

text = "Rose fell"-> This is not a palindrome

```
text = 'MrOwl ate my metal worm'.lower().split()
for i in text:       #this is where the problem arises, I go through all the elements, but I don't know how to put them back together, so that later I can work as with a string
text1=-?
print('MrOwl ate my metal worm" -> This is a palindrome' if text1[::-1] == text1 else "This is not a palindrome")
```

Comment: Are you assuming there is no punctuation?

Comment: Just spaces between words and that's it

Comment: You need to go through the tutorial on strings. SO is not for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the whitespaces and use the `slice` notation to invert the string and check if it matches the original:

```
original = 'MrOwl ate my metal worm'
text = original.replace(" ", "").lower()
if text[::-1] == text:
    print(f"{original} is a palindrome")
```

Comment: Please,explain the design in the print

Comment: It's called `f strings` it is used to evaluate `variables` or `expressions` and add it directly to your string.  you can read more about it in the docs.